# Why I'm getting constant values for a arbitrary point?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Consider a circle with center at origin and a fixed point $A=(a_1,a_2)$ lying on it (I think these two conditions describe the circle completely and uniquely because center is known and radius is known too as $\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$ ). Now, at $A$ a tangent is drawn to the circle. Picture up to now gonna look like this,

[image]

Now, consider an arbitrary point $P=(x_1,x_2)$ on the circle, therefore, $y_1=\sqrt{r^2 - x_1^2}$ where $r^2 = a_1^2 +a_2^2 $. Draw a tangent at $P$ and let this this tangent meet the tangent at $A$ in $T$. Join $A$ to $P$. Picture up to now gonna look like this,
[image]

We can see that $AP$ is the chord of contact, and theorem

> If $T$ is a point with coordinates $(x',y')$ and from it two tangents are drawn to a circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ then the equation to the chord of contact is $$x'x + y'y = r^2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

We can write the equation to $AP$ as $$ \frac{y-a_2}{x-a_1} = \frac{y_1-a_2}{x_1-a_1}$$ and doing some little rearrangements we have $$(a_2 - y_1)x + (x_1 - a_2)y = a_2x_1 - a_1y_1$$ If we compare it with equation (1) then we can say (as far as I think but  according to me this is the *real unsure thing*) $$ a_2x_1 - a_1y_1 = r^2$$
$$ a_2x_1 -a_1\sqrt{r^2 - x_1^2} = r^2$$
$$ a_1^2(r^2 - x_1^2) = (r^2 - a_2x_1)^2$$
$$ a_1^2r^2 - a_1^2x_1^2 = r^4 + a_2^2x_1^2 - 2r^2a_2x_1$$
$$ 0 = x_1^2(a_1^2 +a_2^2) - 2r^2a_2x_1 + r^4 - a_1^2r^2 ~~~~\rightarrow 0= x_1^2r^2 - 2r^2a_2x_1 +r^4 - a_1^2r^2$$ (since $a_1^2 +a_2^2 = r^2$)
$$ x_1^2 -2a_2x_1 +r^2 - a_1^2 =0$$ 
Solving this and using the fact that $a_1^2 + a_2^2 = r^2$ we would get $x_1 = a_2$ and consequently $y_1 = a_1$. My problem is that I considered $(x_1,y_1)$ to be completely arbitrary but they came out to be constants. What does this tell us? Doesn't it say that tangent at $(a_1,a_2)$ can be intersected only by a tangent at $(a_2,a_1)$ ?

P.S. :- This situation has arrived during the solution of the this problem:
**The tangent at any point P of a circle meets the tangent at a fixed point A in T, and T is joined to B, the other end of the diameter through A; prove that the locus of the intersection of AP and BT is an ellipse whose eccentricity is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$**. 
I couldn't solve this question even now (although mentioning this is completely immaterial here).

Comment: How do you know that you can equate the coefficients of the equation that you derived with those of equation (1)? Perhaps one equation is a multiple of the other instead of being identical.

Comment: Incidentally, the original problem that you were trying to solve is related to the [Steiner generation of an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Steiner_generation).

Comment: @amd What if the multiplying factor is 1? By the way thank you very much for pointing that out. I just want to know what would happen if we assume the equations to be totally identical.

Comment: The constant factor could be equal to $1$, but you don’t know that at the point that you identify the two equations.

Comment: What you’ve found is that for the two equations of the secant to be identical, the two points on the circle must be 90° apart (there’s a second solution to your equations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m going to use $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ for the two points on the circle for consistency of notation. Your equation of the line through these two points then becomes $$(y_2-y_1)x+(x_1-x_2)y = x_1y_2-x_2y_1.\tag2$$ So far, so good. However, you can’t assume that this equation is identical to equation (1): they might be multiples of each other. This means in particular that you can’t conclude that the right-hand side of the above equation is equal to $r^2$.

At this point, if you’re trying to verify equation (1), you’ll need to compute the coordinates of $T$, plug them into (1) and show that the two equations define the same line. Omitting the details of the calculations, $$T={r^2\over x_1y_2-x_2y_1}\left(y_2-y_1,x_1-x_2\right).$$ This seems plausible. If the two points are the ends of a diameter, the above denominator vanishes, which corresponds to the two parallel tangents having no (finite) intersection. If you plug this into equation (1), rearrange and remove the common factor of $r^2$, you should eventually end up with equation (2).

---

As far as the original problem that you were trying to solve goes, I suggest working with the unit circle with $A=(1,0)$. Instead of using a point $P$ on the circle, you can then parameterize $T$ as $(1,t)$ and use formula (1) for line $AP$. An equation for $BT$ is easy to find, as is the intersection for the two lines. Eliminate $t$ from the resulting expression. Any other choice of circle and point $A$ is obtained from this via a similarity, which leaves the eccentricity of a conic invariant.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very nice. I want to know how you got the coordinates of $T$? Is it from solving this system $$x_1 x+ y_1 y = r^2$$ $$x_2 x + y_2 y = r^2$$ ?

Comment: Sir your hint of taking a unit circle has solved my problem. How can you advise such a great think so instantly (I'm trying to be obliged to you) ? Wow! Can we solve it for arbitrary circle and an arbitrary fixed point?

Comment: @adeshmishra One could solve it for the general case directly, but why go to all that trouble? One of the great advantages of analytic methods in geometry is the ability to reduce a general problem to a simpler case via a family of transformations that don’t affect the essential parts of the problem, in this case incidence relationships and eccentricity of conics.

Comment: @adeshmishra The coordinates of $T$ can be found by solving that system or simply by computing the pole of the secant line. When working with tangents and secants of conics, examining pole-polar relationships can often simplify the calculations, as can using the power of a point.